# How can I play two WMV files simultaneously in Windows?

Tags: wmv

I have two WMV files - one with audio (audio.wmv) and one with video (video.wmv). I would like to play them both simultaneously (in sync) in Windows.

How can I do this? I'd prefer any free solutions.

Perhaps it would be easier to merge the two files to one: audio + video?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [movie editing program](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_video_editing_software) to combine the two into one.  I've used Sony Vegas for similar purposes but I'm sure most of the programs at the link provided would suffice.

Comment: I thought that somehow it will be possible without video editing. Anyway thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using Windows Movie Maker for this. Switch it to timeline view to make life easier.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is play them in order without using software to combine the files;

1. Select Files - Go to the folder which the files reside. If the files are named sequentially, hold the SHIFT key down and select the first file then the last files in order to select them all. If they are not namesequentiallyly, then hold the CTRL key down and click the files you want to play.
2. Play the files - Right click and choose play. Your default media player will open and play the files. Most players will play them in name order, so it might be a good idea to rename the files if they are not named sequentially.

Note: My experience has been with Windows Media Player and GOM Player which both act as I have described.

Comment: This will play them sequentially, not simultaneously.

Comment: You are correct. I edited this post after I realized my mistake, but for some reason it didn't show up. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Using VLC player:
Media - Advanced Open File.
Select  your video file, tick the "Show more options" checkbox at the bottom, then the "play another media.." and select your audio file.

Comment: This would be great answer but unfortunately I get message from VLC: No suitable decoder module:
VLC does not support the audio or video format "MSA1". Unfortunately there is no way for you to fix this.